How can I easily remove skin from panga fish?
I want to remove leathery skin from the iridescent shark (Pangasianodon hypophthalmus) before cooking.
How can I do that easily?

Whole fish or a piece of it?

@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, pieces.
